# Are weights in truncreg package broken?

Tags: r, truncation

Am I missing something?

```
library(truncreg)

n <- 10^4
lambda <- 0.3  # Proba y is taken from component 0

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(n))
df$y0 <- pmax(rnorm(n, 10 + df$x, 5), 0)
df$y1 <- pmax(rnorm(n, 2 - 5*df$x, 2), 0)
df$component <- ifelse(runif(n) < lambda, 0, 1)
df$y <- ifelse(df$component == 0, df$y0, df$y1)  # Mixture of censored regressions

plot(df$x, df$y)

model <- truncreg(y ~ x, data=df)  # All data
model.w <- truncreg(y ~ x, data=df, weights=component)  # Only component 1, using weights
model.subset <- truncreg(y ~ x, data=subset(df, component == 1))  # Only component 1, using subset

identical(coefficients(model), coefficients(model.w))  # True -- I expected this to be false
identical(coefficients(model.w), coefficients(model.subset))  # False -- I expected this to be true

## For comparison, here is the same using lm:
model <- lm(y ~ x, data=df)
model.w <- lm(y ~ x, data=df, weights=component)
model.subset <- lm(y ~ x, data=subset(df, component == 1))

identical(coefficients(model), coefficients(model.w))  # False as expected
identical(coefficients(model.w), coefficients(model.subset))  # True as expected
```

Comment: I don't know why you expected the same coefficients for a subset of your component data.  But as to whether weights are 'working,' I'd start by graphing the fitted models (all of them) to see if the curves have observably different shapes.  If not, then your weightset just isn't 'dramatic enough' to matter.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I made some edits -- is it clearer now why I expect model.w and model.subset to have the same coefficients (as they do with lm)?  The variable df$component is constructed to make them identical.

Comment: One other note:  `truncreg` doesn't treat the `weights` argument as part of the formula, so even if it did use the weights, you'd have to enter it as `df$component` -- I verified this via `debug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, I can reproduce your problem.
Then I tried setting `method="model.frame"` in the `lm` runs, and get the same "unexpected" results you got, i.e. same coefficients with or without weights applied.   I peeked at the `truncreg` source and didn't see any obvious place that it "chooses"  **not** to use `method="model.frame"` ; then I dug into the `truncreg.fit` source and again didn't see any reference to the weights values.  It's not clear to me what *is* being done, so the weights may well be being passed into the fit code but I might start by digging more carefully thru that code.

Comment: That's correct, the weights do not appear to be used in fitting. It appears, to include weights one would modify the internal function `ml.truncreg` which contains functions for the log-likelihood, hessian, and gradient, that are then passed to `maxLik` for fitting.

Comment: @NatePope thanks for confirming.  I suppose the cheap fix would be to use the weight values to "augment" the input `x` and `y` data before calling `truncreg`.

Comment: Was this bug ever reported to the package maintainer?

Comment: @Carl not by me :-);  you might want to check whether there's been an update to the package since Jan'14, and then try to reproduce the apparent bug yourself.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft FWIW, I was told to use the `crch` package rather than `truncreg` by the package author